# Stream live video via iOS to facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, live-video

Is it possible to stream a live video on Facebook from iOS app ? I've searched the iOS SDK but didn't found anything related. After searching further I've found that I can POST cURL

```
curl -k -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/$your_userid_or_pageid/live_videos \
-F "access_token=$your_user_or_page_token" \
-F "published=true"
```

and a process should be followed after this. 
Dose this mean that I need a middle server between client App and Facebook to get the stream and stream it to Facebook ?

Comment: Use the Live Video API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video-api

Comment: I was looking inside that link but can't find the part where I deliver the stream come from my camera to Facebook server.

Comment: You stream it to the stream_url. And you need to do that over the rtmp protocol

Comment: Be aware that the Live API is not supposed to be used for content from mobile phone cameras.

Comment: @WizKid thank you so much your comment enlighten me :)

Comment: @CBroe sorry I didn't catch this, what do you mean by "is not supposed to be used for content from mobile phone cameras"

Comment: Facebook wants you to use Live Videos for “professional” looking videos only - produced with high-quality equipment, by people who have experience in doing this stuff. They don’t want you to use shaky, low-quality video from a mobile phone camera.

Comment: @CBroe If that's real then why they provide this feature in their Mobile App on iOS and android ?

Answer (score 3):

**Edited**

Facebook offers a Live Video API in their SDK, you can find that here: [Facebook Live Video API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video-api)

Delivering your stream to the Facebook Server's is the difficult part.  I suggest using the [VideoCore API](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) for delivery, just edit the destination information.

Comment: so I can directly communicate with Facebook to send my stream ? I was looking inside that link but can't find the part where I deliver the stream come from my camera to Facebook server.

Comment: see the edit to my answer, Facebook is just the streaming server (endpoint)... the actual code for sending the stream from your app isn't going to be given to you from Facebook, you write that on your own

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Thank you so much I think it's clear now how it will be implemented

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, you should use
`[FBSDKGraphRequest initWithGraphPath:parameters:HTTPMethod]`

to get the RTMP streaming address according to [Facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)